Формирование сводной таблицы из двух динамических массивов
Имеется таблица Equipments



UUID
Название
Суммарное количество на складе




1
Название 1
415


2
Название 2
814


3
Название 3
186



и таблица Orders



UUID
№ Заказа
Поставщик
Количество в заказе
Изделие
Прочая информация




1
192921101
Поставщик 1
123
2
etc.


2
101410824
Поставщик 2
61
1
etc.



Необходимо сформировать сводную таблицу по Изделиям/Заказам с расчетом остатков вида:



UUID
Название
Суммарное количество на складе
Поставщик 1
Поставщик 2
Поставщик 3
...
Остаток




1
Название 1
415
-
61
-
-
354


2
Название 2
814
123
-
-
-
691



Необходима реализация либо средствами SQL (Oracle) либо JS.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

How to convert rows to columns (PIVOT) and back again (UNPIVOT) with SQL in Oracle Database


Необходима реализация либо средствами SQL (Oracle) либо JS.

Предложу такой вариант реализации на JS...


const ot = document.querySelector('table')
const equipments = [
    {
        uuid: 1,
        name: 'Название 1',
        count: 415
    },
    {
        uuid: 2,
        name: 'Название 2',
        count: 814
    },
    {
        uuid: 3,
        name: 'Название 3',
        count: 186
    },
]
const me = new Map(equipments.map(({uuid, name, count}) => [uuid, {name, count}]))
const orders = [
    {
        uuid: 1,
        num: 192921101,
        provider: 'Поставщик 1',
        count: 123,
        equipment: 2,
        bother: 'etc.'
    },
    {
        uuid: 2,
        num: 101410824,
        provider: 'Поставщик 2',
        count: 61,
        equipment: 1,
        bother: 'etc.'
    },
]
const ap = [...new Set(orders.map(o => o.provider))]
const res = [...orders.reduce((m, o) => {
    const e = me.get(o.equipment)
    if (!m.has(e.name)) m.set(e.name, {
        name: e.name, 
        sum: e.count,
        ap: Array(ap.length).fill(0),
        rem: e.count
    })
    const obj = m.get(e.name)
    const i = ap.indexOf(o.provider)
    obj.ap[i] += o.count
    obj.rem -= o.count
    m.set(e.name, obj)
    return m
}, new Map).values()].sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.name === b.name) return 0
    if (a.name > b.name) return 1
    return -1
})
let obj = ot.querySelector('thead th:last-child')
ap.forEach(v => obj.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', `<th>${v}</th>`))
obj = ot.querySelector('tbody')
res.forEach((o, i) => {
    const or = document.createElement('tr')
    or.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<td>${i + 1}</td>`)
    or.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<td>${o.name}</td>`)
    or.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<td>${o.sum}</td>`)
    o.ap.forEach(v => or.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<td>${v ? v : '-'}</td>`))
    or.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<td>${o.rem}</td>`)
    obj.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd', or)
})
<table border='1'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>UUID</th>
        <th>Название</th>
        <th>На складе</th>
        <th>Остаток</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>



